# odoo:How to make list of records readonly based in condition

Tags: odoo

Hi everybody I work on the project module. I have a button to close the project.i need when press this button All the tasks related by project became read-only can you help how can build this function

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your own project module?

You probably have many2one -relation between your project and your task. Bring related field from your project to your task model which tells status of your project. Then you can use that info in `attrs` parameter in your task model field description.

More about related fields: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-use-related-field-in-odoo-11-135643

More about attrs parameter in field definition: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-make-readonly-field-base-on-condition-34796

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` to specify a conditional read-only state based on other fields.

```
<field name="task_ids" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'done')]}"
```

If you need also to make tasks `read-only` in their form view, you can use the same logic.

Comment: I agree with you this work with field but not work with records form view in

Comment: Do you need to set the form view read-only dynamically with one expression?

Comment: Regardless of the expression, I want a way to  make the whole form view read-only based on condition state

Comment: The form view is opened in read-only mode and you need to click on the edit button, do you need to disable the edit button?

Comment: @sami I added an example at [how to disable edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842716/how-to-make-specific-records-in-tree-view-and-form-view-not-editable-in-odoo/61862130#61862130)