# How to make specific records in tree view and form view not editable in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I have an entity bill (spanish factura) with an "state" (selection) attribute. Is it possible to make all records in "Bill" with (state='pendiente' or state='pagad') readonly ? That means that when the user clicks on an specific bill on the tree view, he cannot edit any of the "bill" fields. This is my code

```
class PlanificacionFactura(models.Model):
    _name = 'utepda_planificacion.factura'
    _rec_name = 'numero'
    _description = 'Factura'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

    fecha = fields.Date(string='Fecha')
    monto_total = fields.Monetary(string='Monto a pagar', currency_field='currency_id')
    pago_acumulado = fields.Monetary(compute='_compute_pago_acumulado', string='Pago Acumulado' ,currency_field='currency_id')
    currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string='Moneda', required=True, domain=[('name', 'in', ('USD', 'DOP'))] , default=lambda self: self.env.ref("base.DOP"))
    pago_pendiente = fields.Monetary(compute='_compute_pago_pendiente', string='Pendiente de pago', currency_field='currency_id')

    state = fields.Selection([
        ('creado', 'Creada'),
        ('pendiente','Pagada parcialmente'),
        ('pagado','Pagada')
    ], string='Estado', default='pagado', compute='_compute_state' )

    @api.depends('pago_acumulado','monto_total')
    def _compute_state(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.pago_acumulado > 0 and record.pago_acumulado < record.monto_total:
                record.state='pendiente'
            elif record.pago_acumulado == record.monto_total:
                record.state = 'pagado'
            else:
                record.state='creado'
    @api.model
    def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
        res = super(PlanificacionFactura, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
        if view_type == 'form':
            doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='fecha']"):
                node.set('options', "{'datepicker': {'maxDate': '%s'}}" % fields.Date.today().strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT))

            if 'params' in self.env.context and 'id' in self.env.context['params']:
                values = self.search_read([('id', '=', self.env.context['params']['id'])], fields=['state'])
                if values[0]['state'] == 'pagado':
                    # Disable edit mode on form view based on `state` field
                    for node in doc.xpath("//form"):
                        node.set('edit', '0')

            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
        return res
```

I made the state visible i the statusbar

```
    <header>
        <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
    </header>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `attrs="{'readonly': [('paid', '=', True)]}"`?

Comment: I cannot apply that atribute to the entire form. The Idea is to open the form in readonly mode

Comment: The form is opened in read-only mode, you have to click on the edit button to make fields editable. Do you mean by making the form not editable, hiding the edit button?

Comment: Read [Developer Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/) and I advise you to start with [Building a Module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can override `FormRenderer` to check for the `state` field just after the form has loaded.

You can specify the condition as a domain and use [web.Domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) class to compute it using current record field values.

```
var FormRenderer = require('web.FormRenderer');
var Domain = require("web.Domain");
FormRenderer.include({

    autofocus: function () {
        this.show_hide_edit_button();
        return this._super();
    },

    show_hide_edit_button : function () {
        if( 'disable_edit_mode' in this.arch.attrs && this.arch.attrs.disable_edit_mode) {
            var domain = Domain.prototype.stringToArray(this.arch.attrs.disable_edit_mode)
            var button = $(".o_form_button_edit");
            if (button) {
                var hide_edit = new Domain(domain).compute(this.state.data);
                // If you just need to disable edit button
                // button.prop('disabled', hide_edit);
                
                // button is shown if the parameter is true and hidden if it is false
                button.toggle(!hide_edit);
            }
        }
    },

});
```

Use `disable_edit_mode` attribute to set you domain conditions:

```
<form disable_edit_mode="[('state', '=', 'pagado')]">
```

Refer to [Adding files in an asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) to add the above code to your module.